# DNS problems with a static IP configuration in a VM

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine

I am using Parallels Desktop 10.2 for Mac on OS X Yosemite. I am trying to configure my my client (Ubuntu 14.04) to host a website that is available to the host via a particular domain name.

In the advanced network settings, I configured the shared start address (since the host is sharing its network with this VM) to be 10.211.55.20—the ending address is 10.211.55.254. And I changed my /etc/network/interfaces file such that eth0 is configured statically.

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.211.55.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.211.55.20
```

This works to an extent. After adding an entry to the host's /etc/hosts file, I can access the client server via the hostname I specified. However, other domain names don't resolve on the client. I've done some extensive searching to figure out what gives and can't find a solution that works for me. I've tried adding the line `dns-nameservers 10.211.55.20` and (in a different attempt) `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` (Google's public DNS) to no avail. I tried adding an entry to the /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base file also to no avail. Any ideas as to what I'm missing or doing wrong? I'm still pretty new to networking, so I don't entirely know what I'm doing outside of the help I can find via Google.

Additionally, if somebody could guide me on how to configure this for IPv6, that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8 and get a response?  If you cannot, then you actually have a routing issue and not a DNS issue.

Comment: @IceMage, no, that doesn't work. Also, I'm being told that I should bridge the network instead of sharing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a route to the internet configured for the virtual network your VMs reside in.  You should try seeing if you can put your VMs in a transparent bridge, or configure a router for the virtual machine network.  If you cannot ping 8.8.8.8 from your network, then you must address the routing issue before you can address your DNS issues.

Ensure that you can do all of the following in the following order.

1. Ping your local machine on it's private IP
2. Ping your default gateway on it's internal IP.
3. Ping your computer hosting the VM.
4. Ping a common IP on the internet (e.g. 8.8.8.8)

Comment: I think I broke something and don't remember what I did. I ended up setting up a fresh VM and bridged the host's network to it and set up the IP to still be statically assigned. So the part of your answer regarding bridging is correct, so I'll mark your answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

I completely missed the part where you were able to access it via a /etc/hosts entry.

The IP range you gave it looks like the DHCP range, so setting its IP to .1 probably conflicts. Set it to 10.211.55.5 or something a little higher.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything different. Still can't resolve any domains.